# Is it possible to make [XmlAttribute] as default for a class?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a lot of properties to serialize using `XmlSerializer`. I need to tag each (simple) property with `[XmlAttribute]` to make the output a little shorter. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it. Is there a way to make it as a default for a class, so that all simple type properties will be serialized as attribute instead of element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).

Create one for properties with the attribute already set, and use it when writing them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't understand how code snippets can help me here. I'd appreciate very much if you could elaborate a little more.

Comment: @miliu - If you create a code snippet, every time you want to create a property that is decorated with `XmlAttribute` you can use it. Granted, this will not help if you want to decorate _existing_ properties.

Answer (score 2):

No, basically. Well, you *could* do the work at runtime using `XmlAttributeOverrides`, inspecting your types in code and setting the attributes appropriately, then making sure you cache the serializer (if you don't cache when using `XmlAttributeOverrides` you leak memory, as the generated assemblies aren't collected). But that sounds like *more* work.

Re making the output shorter; xml compresses with GZip or Deflate very nicely...

Of course, if you don't need *xml*, but just need the data serialized *somehow*, there are other options.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tip. It does seem more work. I guess I have to live with individual tags. Compress with GZip or binay serialization is not an option becuase the output needs to be human readable.